# How to get the half 64bit of Vn.8h in armv8 like D register in armv7？

Tags: arm, simd, neon

I load the data like this:

`ld1    {v8.8h, v9.8h, v10.8h, v11.8h}, [%8], #64`

But when I use the data to calculate, it goes wrong:

```
smlal   v16.4s, v8.2d[0], v0.h[0]
```

The error is:

> /tmp/cc2h1F9Y.s:523: Error: operand 2 must be a SIMD vector register -- `smlal v16.4s,v8.2d[0],v0.h[0]'

So I want to know how to get the half 64bit of Vn.8h in armv8 like D register in armv7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is multiply a scalar with a vector.

You can use the smlal2 instruction to solve this.

smlal v16.4s, v8.4h, v0.h[0]

This will multiply the low 64bit.

smlal2 v16.4s, v8.8h, v0.h[0]

And this will multiply the high 64bit.

For those who confused by this...